# Heroku 500 Error, while using Heroku, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to upload images to S3 using paperclip. It currently works perfectly in development, but when I push it to heroku I get a status 500.

I've looked on current topics and some reasons for this are either the lack of a pg gem and bucket name not configured but I've checked those.

My error log currently says this

```
2014-06-22T23:13:44.118505+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.118013 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: convert '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+99+0" +repage -set colorspace sRGB -strip '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-10cae74.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040021+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:31.758844 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered patients/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040023+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:31.759625 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040024+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.027440 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/patients" for 107.19.177.84 at 2014-06-22 23:13:44 +0000
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040026+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.031624 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PatientsController#create as HTML
2014-06-22T23:13:44.081130+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.080608 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' 2>/dev/null
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040028+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.031790 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6LvlNWsTg6qCoILIbt1pjvUX1mvP+WbnHUX4yYVPHdI=", "patient"=>{"name"=>"Yitao Zhang", "number"=>"6503916966", "email"=>"yitaoz@stanford.edu", "appointment"=>"2014-06-16", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f7324f6e7f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140622-2-1gopf5s>, @original_filename="images.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"patient[avatar]\"; filename=\"images.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "description"=>"adsafasdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2014-06-22T23:13:44.184102+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.183584 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-10cae74.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.040030+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.038575 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/8f2ed61a3cb4149d8c9abca38721647720140622-2-1c1dac6'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.260870+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.260288 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: convert '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x480" -crop "480x480+478+0" +repage -set colorspace sRGB -strip '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-ye2lmv.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.470900+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.470357 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-ye2lmv.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.544510+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.543987 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: convert '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' -auto-orient -resize "600>" -set colorspace sRGB -strip '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-1rbg2jr.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.621867+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.621332 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' 2>/dev/null
2014-06-22T23:13:44.590252+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.589723 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-1rbg2jr.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.506015+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.505469 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' 2>/dev/null
2014-06-22T23:13:44.662154+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.661637 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: convert '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y3[0]' -auto-orient -resize "1200>" -set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5 '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-fpzvpn.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.743824+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.743315 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eba6328b7631122493d269f7c5d3781d20140622-2-1f1t7y320140622-2-fpzvpn.jpg'
2014-06-22T23:13:44.836262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/patients" host=glacial-scrubland-2600.herokuapp.com request_id=47cf63e3-59f9-4dc0-be18-fc06ae702775 fwd="107.19.177.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1078ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-06-22T23:13:44.790408+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-06-22T23:13:44.789786 #2]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/47f9c6187d138877e010f0255fe25ac920140622-2-1fmy0hr'
```

The only hint I have is that status=500.

Would really appreciate any thoughts / help!

Comment: Does your heroku environment have whatever keys you need to connect and push to S3?

Comment: It does, and I have the following under has_attached_files

 :s3_credentials => {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**ENV Vars**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

The most pertinent issue will likely be that you've not got your `ENV` variables set up correctly. These are *environment* specific - meaning you will have to set them in each "environment" (server) you deploy your app to

A common problem for many is they will deploy to Heroku without setting these ENV vars, consequently preventing the system from accessing the information it needs.

The solution is to use [`heroku config:set VARIABLE=value` in your CMD](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

--

**Production**

Your log doesn't have any errors, which isn't very helpful

One other piece of speculation, therefore, would be the idea that you've not set the [`production` environment options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) in Rails itself:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

There is another issue you *may* have, which is how `paperclip` uses the `bucket` option. We've found that it requires this setup to work correctly:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip.defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

Comment: My config variables are set, and the production.rb is set too.

Comment: Interesting! Can you post your log for the 500 error? You've posted the log for the upload process; we need to see what happens *after* that

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I double checked and my config variables are set, and the production.rb is laid out the same way that your second code block is. Perhaps there is something wrong with my models definition?

right now my models look something like this

` :s3_credentials => {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },
`

this is under has_attached_file

Comment: Can you post your model code? The problem I have is there's no specific error to see - it would be *really* helpful to see the error on the request after the upload process has happened

Comment: sorry for the double comment internet was a little wonky there

How can I post the log for the 500 error? Thanks again so much for helping me out!

Comment: Np - you can get the error by just typing `heroku logs` and it should return the latest returned data. Alternatively, you can install the [logentries](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) add-on, which will allow you to track the errors in real time

Comment: I tried that again, the log that I generated from that is here
http://pastebin.com/Qf5XHM7B

I noticed there is an error of integer out of range but that has never stopped it on the dev environment, not sure what else it could be

Comment: Well *any* error is bad news, and needs to be fixed :) Do you know why the `out of range` error may appear? It looks like it's for your `Patient` model (not your images?)

Comment: I think I just got something more concrete. Its a socket error here: http://pastebin.com/bNAyK0rm

Comment: My hypothesis is that the paperclip save failed, so the db save rolled back, so when my controller tries to display the data saved by the latest db entry it comes up with an error?

Comment: Nice! The question is now - where do you call `getaddrinfo`?

Comment: Well to test that, you can run `heroku run rails c` locally & load up the patient records you're trying to show in your browser. You'll be able to see the values which were saved

Comment: I searched my rails files and it doesn't have getaddrinfo in any lines of code. 

Also unfortunately Im not sure how to use the console for heroku :(

Comment: I got it working!! turns out that you were right about production.rb, but I copied your host name without checking too closely and I looked again you are using eu when I am using us. So i made that change and it worked.

Comment: Nice! Glad it worked for you sir!