# Upload image to S3 through Heroku by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, grape-api

I'd like to upload image from iOS to S3 through Heroku by paperclip. I've used this website as reference. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

However, it return the error "status code: 500, headers". I'm not sure what is the problem. I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

```
#terminal
$heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME="kenja.jp"
$heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my_access_key_id
$heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my_secret_access_key

#app/models/user.rb
has_attached_file :photo, 
  :styles => { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'kenja.jp',
  :s3_permissions => :public,
  :url => ":s3_domain_url",
  :path => "/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :s3_host_name => "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com",
  :s3_credentials => :"#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"


#config/environments/staging.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['kenja.jp'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['my_access_key_id'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['my_secret_access_key']
  }
}


#config/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] ='/:class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extenstion'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'


#app/apis/v1/users.rb
  params do  
    requires :id, type:Integer
    requires :icon, type:Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
  end
  post '/post_picture' do
    photo_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(params[:icon])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(photo: photo_file)
    @user.photo
  end
```

---

## Logs

I've checked heroku logs, then it said the following.

```
2015-10-18T06:33:10.144859+00:00 app[web.1]:  app/apis/v1/users.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Users>'
2015-10-18T06:33:10.144858+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):
2015-10-18T06:33:10.128265+00:00 app[web.1]:  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
```

This link told me that I need to downgrade the version of aws-sdk. [NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws)

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

Comment: What do you see in your heroku log?

Comment: See if this post's accepted answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356759/heroku-500-error-while-using-heroku-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

> NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS)

After looking online, this is basically caused by the `aws-sdk` `v2` gem not having the `AWS` module defined. In short, this means that Paperclip is unable to call the module required to save its data to S3.

The workaround is to downgrade your `aws-sdk` version to `1`:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

... however, *who likes workarounds?*

You *should* be able to get it working if you [pull from the `Paperclip master branch`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1764):

```
#Gemfile
gem "paperclip", git: "https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git", branch: "master"
```